# HTML part not showing up on my website

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a login and sign up page but I can't seem to make the HTML part show up. I think it is something wrong with the PHP code. I am hosting it on a website that has access to PHPMyAdmin and MySQL. I have looked up my problem and can't find any answers. I have checked the syntax but it is still not working. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['sig']))
{
   #User is already logged in
   echo("<script>window.location='home.php'</script>");
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])
{
   #Perform login action
   $username=$_REQUEST['UserUsername'];
   $password=$_REQUEST['UserPassword'];

   include ('db_login.php');
   $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserUsername='".$username."' AND UserPassword='".$password."'");
   $row=mysql_fetch_arr($query);
   if(empty($row))
   {
      #False Info / User doesn't exist
      echo('<script>alert("False login credentials!");</script'));
   }
   else
   {
      #User exists and login is successful
      $_SESSION['sig']="OK";
   }

}

?>
```

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: 1. You never print anything to screen when login is successful, which "HTML" part doesn't print, and when? 2. You need to stop using MySQL_ commands, they are outdated and incredibly insecure.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: you're using mysql_query instead of mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly.

Comment: You call a function that doesn't exist and have error reporting turned off so PHP cannot tell you about it. But, even if this code worked, you have no output to see anyway.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.